# Arithmetic overflow casting LDAP lastLogon

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, ldap

I am trying to convert an LDAP lastLogon value to an SQL DateTime value utilizing this code:

`DATEADD(MS, CAST(lastLogon AS BIGINT), '19700101')`

where lastLogin is the AD value for the user's latest login.
I receive this error:

`Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.`

I am checking for null and using ISNUMERIC.
We are running 2008 R2. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `lastLogon` value is too large, `DATEADD()` accepts an `INT` value not a `BIGINT`.

You can workaround this with multiple steps, dividing your time into smaller chunks of bigger units, i.e. Seconds first, then milliseconds:

```
DATEADD(MS,CAST(lastLogon AS BIGINT)%1000,DATEADD(SECOND, CAST(lastLogon AS BIGINT)/1000, '19700101'))
```

I think `Week` is as large as you can go in your first step, as a month's worth of milliseconds won't fit into an `INT`, but I'd probably stick with `DAY` for simplicity:

```
DATEADD(MS,CAST(lastLogon AS BIGINT)%(1000*60*60*24),DATEADD(DAY, CAST(lastLogon AS BIGINT)/(1000*60*60*24), '19700101'))
```

Answer (score 0):

too late. but found solution
sample:

```
select  dateadd(day,130787731801583080 / (60 * 10000000) / 1440  - (datediff(dd, '1/1/1900', dateadd(yy, 299, '1/1/1900'))), '1/1/1900')
```